# gcloud: Find all VMs in a specific Network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-cli

How can I use gcloud to list all VMs in a specific GCE network? `gcloud compute instances list` lists all VMs in all the networks in my project. If I do `gcloud compute instances describe foo` on each, I can see the network, but doing that for each is laborious. Is there a single command I can run to filter the results?

Answer (score 1):

gcloud compute  instances list --filter="networkInterfaces.network:(regex)"

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filtering:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters

Specifically:

`gcloud compute instances list --filter 'networkInterfaces.network:<network_name>
'`